# Can't use custom themes, Gnome Shell 3.2

Tags: gnome, themes, customization

I can't manage to get gnome tweak tool to allow me to switch themes, nor to install the required extensions and have them working. Could anyone please give me any pointers?

**EDIT**: Fixed it, but I forgot how I did it. Sorry.

Comment: Are you installing the themes on the correct directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to face this problem again, and found a solution:

[Original blog post here](http://joesteiger.com/2011/11/14/install-gnome-shell-themes-with-the-user-theme-extension-and-gnome-tweak-tool-ubuntu-11-10/)

Istall the user-theme extension from ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

Restart by logging out and back in or with `ALT-F2` and `r`.

Open the gnome tweak tool, go to Shell Extensions, enable the User Themes Extension.

Close the tweak tool restart gnome-shell again.

Now open the gnome tweak tool again and, under theme, you should be able to select your shell theme.